# Is the sentence correct: Tell us whether to hike on the hill

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence correct: Tell us whether to hike on the hill or not.

(　　)Tell us whether___________or not.
　
(A)to hike on a hill　(B)can we hike on a hill　
(C)we can hike on a hill　(D)hike on a hill

This is a grammar question, and the answer is C. I am wondering why A is not correct. Is it because we don't use "whether to V or not" very often?  Or is it because of two different subjects in the sentences.

Comment: Yet another silly textbook question. Yes, A is grammatically correct; it would mean 'tell us whether we should hike on the hill', while C means 'tell us whether it is possible to hike on the hill".

Comment: Since ***on a hill*** occurs after *every* instance of ***hike*** in the choices, that part is obviously not *syntactically* relevant to the question. And *semantically* it's almost impossible to imagine a credible context for any of the choices. Why do these (obviously non-Anglophone) test-setters so often choose such bizarre examples? What's wrong with plain *Tell us whether **to go / we can go / ...** or not*?

Answer (score 2):

A is grammatically correct English.

It would probably never actually be used. The question is rather ridiculous. Why ask someone if you should "hike on a hill"? Instead of what, "hike in a valley"? That's not a normal interaction about hiking choices!

C is as ridiculous, for similar reasons.

But there is no grammar error.

Comment: I suppose either might make sense in appropriate context. Like if I was recovering from a broken leg, I might ask the doctor if it is now safe for me to hike on a hill or if I should limit myself to flat ground. But yes, taken in isolation, strange request. It would make more sense if it was "the hill". "Should I hike on this particular hill or is that private property?" (Or infested with rattle snakes or some other reason not to hike there.)

Comment: In those very specfic conditions you would say, "Tell me whether it is safe for me to go hiking on the hills".  Saying "Tell us whether to hike on a hill or not" would not be a fluent way to ask that question, and this is what I mean by "ridiculous".  It is bad enough that an English Learner would be exposed to ridicule if they used a sentence like this, even though it is grammatically well formed.

Comment: I'm basically agreeing with you. I'm just adding the routine caveat that a sentence that sounds illogical or ambiguous if examined in isolation can make perfect sense in context. In this case, if in context we have been talking about what is and is not safe, and we've used the word "safe" or "safety" ten times already, it may well be redundant and unnecessary to use it again.